# Why do the center numbers of a 5 XOR set always equal the 1st and 5th number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

This question is to why something happens, and i'm wondering if it has a quantum nature or if the result can be explained just by classical means. So....

I have noticed that on a 5 xor that the 1st number and last number always equals the xor of the distances between all numbers. Can anyone let me know why that is and if it's of any
significance? "^" being the XOR symbol for the discussion below.

For example 1^11^3^11^4 has the distances between them as 10^8^8^15. Now 10^8^8^15 = 5.  So does 1^4 = 5 in the first sequence. This holds true no matter what numbers
are in the center, the distances will always xor to the 1st and 5th number of the original sequence. So if i had 1^11^9^11^4 the distances are 5^13^2^15 which again, equals 5.
No matter how hard you try, the distances between the numbers will always equal the xor of the first and 5th number of the original sequence you took the distances of.
What's interesting to me about this is that the 1st and 5th number have no knowledge of the center numbers but however the logic of xor works, the distances between the numbers
always collapses to the result of the 1st and 5th number of the original sequence. So from a logic standpoint, your xors of the distances between 5 numbers will always result in
the same as the first and last number of the original sequence, even without knowledge of the center numbers. So the logic of XOR seems not to care of the center number.

Now from a philosphical/quantum standpoint, would that mean you could entangle the numbers in a way which knows the original middle sequence?  would love to hear from anyone interested in this idea that if this is a quantum solvable problem, finding those center numbers

Here i present the XOR of the logic, the first column using the following logic required to get the final result holds for the new sequence.
So that logic for the first column is always: 4 1's = 1, 3 1's = 0, 2 1's = 0, and 1 1's = 1.  A different logic set that always holds true in this case.

1st column is the original sequence the second column is the distance. Notice that logic does not break in the first column of each number sequence if you use the above logic
. so if you change how XOR logic worked with 5 numbers, with the logic above, you end up with 0b0101 which is 5. The second (distance) column using normal XOR logic. You can
arrive at the same number with the original numbers if you use a different logic set for any numbers between 2 and 4 in a sequence of 5 if you use as the first column logic as i
presented above, once again being:  4 1's = 1, 3 1's = 0, 2 1's = 0, and 1 1's = 1.

```
1^11^3^11^4       1^11^9^11^4
  
0b0001            0b0001 
0b1011  0b1010    0b1011  0b1010
0b0011  0b1000    0b1001  0b0010
0b1011  0b1000    0b1011  0b0010
0b0100  0b1111    0b0100  0b1111
                  
0b0101  0b0101    0b0101  0b0101
```

So there is a logic with some underpinning that i can't grasp (which is why the hell do those middle numbers always align with logic???) and i think it is something quantum in nature.
What do you think? I mean the center numbers always align with logic? Why? That's weird, but somehow they always do. Is logic an underpinning of the number system somehow?  It's just seems to me that classical logic hides the logical underpinnings of randomness, so even though they are random numbers, logic will always dictate the result anyways.

So my question is why does logic work when random numbers are used in the center? Is there a mathematical answer to this question, is there a quantum aspect to this, or is it logic just somehow connected to randomness in this case?

Comment: I have seen XOR used in logical statements but not arithmetic.  Can you define how to calculate "a^b" for us?

Comment: What do you mean by "distance"?  In your first example, you say that the distance between $1$ and $11$ is $10$, and the distance between $4$ and $11$ is $15$.  Why isn't the latter $7$?

Comment: @RobertTheTutor:  It is bitwise in binary, so $10\text ^15=1010_2\text ^ 1111_2=0101_2=5$

Comment: @RobertTheTutor It's bitwise addition, modulo $2$.

Comment: @saulspatz because the xor of 4 binary(0b0100) and 11 binary(0b1011),  equals 15 binary(0b1111)

Comment: Parcly's answer is excellent and you should accept it. But just in case it isn't completely clear to you, he's telling you that what you're doing is essentially this:$$
(a \oplus b) \oplus (b \oplus c) \oplus (c \oplus d) \oplus (d \oplus e) \\
a \oplus (b \oplus b) \oplus (c \oplus c) \oplus (d \oplus d) \oplus e \\
a \oplus 0 \oplus 0 \oplus 0 \oplus e \\
a \oplus e \\
$$
There is no quantum, nor entanglement here, just boolean algebra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can look at every bit position separately since bitwise XOR does not mingle bits from different positions, thus reducing the problem to sets of bits.

XOR is equivalent to addition in $\mathbb F_2$, so it is commutative, associative and obeys the following identity.
$$b\oplus b=0$$
Hence for any $n$ bits $b_1,\dots,b_n$
$$\bigoplus_{k=1}^{n-1}b_k\oplus b_{k+1}=b_1\oplus b_2\oplus b_2\oplus b_3\oplus b_3\oplus b_4\oplus\dots\oplus b_n=b_1\oplus b_n$$

Comment: Wow, after several tries I still can't even read that. I thought an XOR required two inputs.  Where are your inputs?  It looks like $b_1, b_2, ...$ are the bits of a single number, so where is the other number?  And you just said that you can deal with the bits separately so why are you combining them??

Comment: @RobertTheTutor No, the $b_i$ are bits in _the same position_ across different numbers. If you only have a two-input XOR gate you make a multi-input one by XORing results repeatedly until only one remains.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I'm frankly astounded that XOR is associative, but I wrote out the truth table for 3 inputs and it works, so I can understand why what you are doing is well defined.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor Even when you take larger numbers, it still works 1^11^9^11^3^15^7 The distances are 10^2^2^8^12^8 = 6 which is what 1^7 equals!!!
OR 1^4^3^8^3^5^7 which distances are 5^7^11^11^6^2 = 6. So even at larger numbers this works, it just boggles my mind that random numbers
can't overcome logic of the first and last number. Parcly, thank you for the answer